# Method overloading in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I am working with a code that contains following overloaded method in generic class:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void Process(T item) { /*impl*/ }
    public void Process(string item) { /*impl*/ }
}
```

When parametrizing the class for `string` do I lose the possibility to call the version with generic parameter?

```
var a = new A<string>();
a.Process(""); //Always calls the non-generic Process(string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one way I just discovered, but it's a bit cross-eyed. Because generics and overloading get resolved in build time, you can define a generic method:

```
public static CallerClass
{
    public static CallGenericOverload<T>(GenericClass<T> cls, T val)
    {
        return cls.ProblemOverload(val); 
    }   

    //We can also make an extension method. 
    //We don't have to of course, it's just more comfortable this way.
    public static CallGenericOverloadExtension<T>(this GenericClass<T> cls, T val)
    {
        return cls.ProblemOverload(val);
    }

}

public GenericClass<T>
{
     public string ProblemOverload(T val)
     {
         return "ProblemOverload(T val)";
     }
     public string ProblemOverload(string val)
     {
         return "ProblemOverload(string val)";
     }
}
```

Now, if we do the following:

```
var genClass = new GenericClass<string>();
Console.WriteLine(genClass.ProblemOverload("")); //output: ProblemOverload(string val)
Console.WriteLine(CallerClass.CallGenericOverload(genClass, "")); //output: ProblemOverload(T val)
Console.WriteLine(genClass.CallGenericOverloadExtension("")); //output: ProblemOverload(T val)
```

You can use a similar trick if you define a generic class instead of a generic method. The important thing is that the parameter you transfer to `ProblemOverload` needs to be of type `T` rather than type `string` in the invocation. After all, the method `CallGenericOverload` knows it's getting a `T` at build time, so it's going to bind to the overload that accepts the parameter. It doesn't matter that it's actually going to get a `string` at runtime.

Comment: Weird but lovely at the same time!

Answer (score 14):

Specific types take precedence over generic types.

For example, this is what I tested with in LINQPad.

```
void Main()
{
    new A<string>().Process("Hello");
}

public class A<T>
{
    public void Process(T item) { Console.WriteLine("T"); }
    public void Process(string item) { Console.WriteLine("string"); }
}

// Output: string
```

If you have a problem with hiding the generic method, then you need to rethink something. By overloading a generic method with specific types, you are effectively saying, "Use the generic overload if you need to, but if you can, use the specific version, *because it should know what is best.*"

Comment: So I take it then the answer is yes?

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes. This is documented in the C# spec, section 7.5.3, overload resolution.

From 7.5.3.6:

> *"While signatures as declared must be unique, it is possible that substitution of type arguments results in identical signatures. In
>   such cases, the tie-breaking rules of overload resolution above will
>   pick the most specific member."*

The example given in there states that in the case below, overload resolution for `G<int>.F1` will pick non-generic

```
class G1<U>
{
    int F1(U u);
    int F1(int i);
}
```

The tie-breaking rule that applies here is outlined in 7.5.3.2, "Better function member":

> *In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …,
>   QN} are equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the
>   corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in
>   order, to determine the better function member.*

- *If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.*

Comment: Like the answer, don't like the rule... but fortunately you can call the method explictly

Answer (score 0):

Having done this before, I'm inclined to say "No," but there's always more knowledgable folks who would argue otherwise.

If memory serves, the <s>runtime</s> compiler chooses the most strongly typed overload to execute.

**CLARIFICATION**

My answer is badly worded, and I deserve the downvote.

The OP asked, "*When parametrizing the class for string do I lose the possibility to call the version with generic parameter?*" I wasn't answering that "No, you can't do that," but that "No, you don't lose the ability to call the version with the generic parameter."

I should have been more clear.

Comment: Actually, this is resolved at compile time. The runtime doesn't choose anything.

Comment: Well said. I thought that was the case, but that's what I get for posting while under the influnce of Cough Syrup. :-/

Comment: Hm, re. your clarification: actually you DO lose the ability to call te version with the generic parameter (if the parameter is of type string, which is what the OP asks).

Comment: Not if you explicitly call it as I have shown... cough syrup or not... but it does help :P